Why do I get two diffrent responses when using the Inference API feature on thee widget on hugging face compared to one when I run the api locally?
I recently discovered hugging face and have been trying to work with it. When using text-to-text model, I came into the issue. no matter which model, i would get a different response when trying the model in the inference widget of hugging face vs when i would call an API from my machine.
here i the difference:
Screensshot of Widget and its reponse
and here is the code with the output :
def query(payload):
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors
    return response.json()

output = query({
        "inputs": "Can you please tell me something about a Python programming lnaguage?",
    })

print("Unexpected response format:", output)

output being :
Can you please tell me something about a Python programming lnaguage?
-
Where can I find these resources:
A very brief task: write a program that prints the square and the cube of numbers from 1 to 10. Collect the user input and print the result. The program will end here.

Python code:

    # Python code to find square and cube of numbers
    for i in range(1, 1好好谱(10)):
        print("Square of", i

why is this happening and how to fix it?

In the widget, your text is automatically converted in an appropriate chat format, including special tokens.
To do the same locally, I would recommend the Inference Hub library
